# How can I untar a sub directory?

Tags: linux, tar

Suppose I have a tar that contains:

```
/                # Root directory
/level1/         # A sub directory
/level1/a.file
/level1/b.file
/level1/...      # The rest
```

How can I do something like `tar -xf` that would untar the contents `level1/` like this:

```
/a.file
/b.file
/...       # The rest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as it involves a simple sub-directory like my original question, I found I can do this:

```
tar -xzf mytar.tgz --strip-components 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`tar -axf mytar.tgz level1/ --strip-components 1`

Answer (score -3):

```
tar xf mytar.tar
mv /level1/* .
```

Comment: That'll leave all the other contents of the tar all over the current directory.  At least use `tar xf mytar.tar level1`.

Comment: *ghostdog74, your command unzip the whole archive, not only subdirectory